# Rails: Running Multiple Ruby Scripts on a Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, background-process

I've a Rails server that runs flawless at the moment (Ruby Enterprise + Passenger + Apache).

It should also to run some independent ruby scripts (setting up localhost XML-RPC servers) on the background.
What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe [this][1] question would be helpful? 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388016/spinning-background-tasks-in-rails      EDIT: Okay, I have no idea why this made this as a comment...

Comment: well found :) thanks.. i'm gonna try starling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link in the comments to another question (by Smar, thanks):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background

seemed to work fine for me. I didn't need Foreman or any other tool.

I just needed to add this to the Rakefile:

```
desc "Start some other jobs"
task :start_other_jobs do
    system "ruby job1.rb &"
    system "ruby job2.rb &"
end
```

(note the ampersand to make it run as a background task)

and then start it by

```
rake start_other_jobs
```

Easy, isn't it? :D

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Foreman](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html). It allows you to specify your background processes in a simple, text-based `Procfile` and run them with `foreman start`.

If you are looking to start your web server and background scripts together with one command, and you're okay with using Passenger Standalone, your `Procfile` might look something like:

```
web:    passenger start
rpc:    ruby rpc_server.rb
worker: script/delayed_job
```

Comment: -this looks much simpler indeed. Do you have any pointers how a procfile looks like? Can find a few very basic examples, but not how the real syntax of the procfile looks like-...EDIT: found a good article at http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Answer (score 0):

I've tried Starling/Workling and found them difficult to configure and keep running as compared to [`delayed_job`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). In any case, you'll need a process monitor like [God](http://god.rubyforge.org/) or [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to make sure whatever solution you choose remains running.