# set a reminder for a todo app in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm totally new to rails. I've prepared a simple todo application with rails 3.0
Need help on adding

Reminder for Todo task set.

Email the reminder.

i'm totally new to rails.

So far i've done:

- install rails and ruby
- rails new app
- rake db:create
- rails g scaffold name:string status:boolean
- rake db:migrate
- added to routes.rb, root to:"tasks#index"
- rails s

Comment: Share code of what you have written for the simple todo application?

Comment: Please check the latest edit.
I don't know what code to post.. there's model, views and controllers.. which one do you want  me to post?

Answer (score 6):

Please follow the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), to get a better understanding of how Rails works.

1. You would need to have models for User and Tasks in place. Create and associate those models, by following along the [first guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). Following this guide, you would know how best to model your application.

   1. You would need models for Users and Tasks with reminders
   2. Users would create those tasks with the expiry / reminder time.
   3. Run a [background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388016/spinning-background-tasks-in-rails) periodically to check for expiry of these tasks and appropriately send email reminders.
2. For emailing follow the guide about ActionMailer - [Action Mailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

Comment: i wish i could read and go through the rails completely but time constraint, i won't be able to do so. Is there a step by step procedure i can complete this?

Comment: @Mirage What happened with the todo app? :-)