# Is it possible to string / queue Ruby actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've written a number of actions in a RoR app, that perform different actions within process.

E.g. 
- One action communicates with a third party service using their API and collects data.
- Another processes this data and places it into a relevant database.
- Another takes this new data and formats it in a specific way.
etc..

I would like to fire off the process at timed intervals, eg. Each hour. But I don't want to do the whole thing each time.

Sometimes I may just want to do the first two actions. At other times, I might want to do each part of the process.

So have one action run, and then when it's finished call another action. ETC..

The actions could take up to an hour to complete, if not longer, so I need a solution that won't timeout.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388016/spinning-background-tasks-in-rails#388043)

Comment: That post is from 2008, so tread lightly

Comment: Have you looked at using cronjobs?

Answer (score 3):

You have quite a few options for processing jobs in the background:

- Sidekiq: http://mperham.github.io/sidekiq/
- Queue Classic: https://github.com/ryandotsmith/queue_classic
- Delayed Job: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job
- Resque: https://github.com/resque/resque

Just read through and pick the one that seems to fit your criteria the best.

**EDIT**
As you clarified, you want regularly scheduled tasks.  Clockwork is a great gem for that (and generally a better option than cron):

- https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork

Comment: Thanks, Sidekiq looks very handy. I should have been explicit in my description with regards to the fact that these would be occurring at recurring intervals. It'll never be triggered by a user. More along the lines of every hour, it would run (action 1 -> action 2). And then every 12 hours it would run (action 3). After a quick search, I think something like Clockwork would be well suited to this, unless there is another gem better suited to the task? (https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork)

Comment: Got it. Yes Clockwork would be good for that -- it persists the background process, so that you don't spend tons of resource spooling up a new environment every time you want to do a job (as happens with cron jobs)

Comment: One last thing. I'm initiating the method calls using rake, which works fine locally. On the server, however, it just appears to time out. Would this be where the use of background_tasks would come into play?